# How to use defer in rxjs timer?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am implementing a countdown timer with goes 5:00, 4:59,4:58...so on.
How should I just use the input value as it is and not have a default assigned? I have an environment variable which configures duration value.

How to use a setter or ngOnChanges to only start the timer once the value is set?

Will the takeWhile run for seconds + 1 ?

Also, given input can change after the component is created how do I create a change handler?

```
export class CountdownComponent {
  @Input() duration = 300
  timeRemaining$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    map(n => (this.seconds - n) * 1000),
    takeWhile(n => n >= 0),
  )
}
```

I tried this.

```
export class CountdownComponent {
  @Input() duration = 300
  timeRemaining$ = defer(of(this.seconds)).pipe(switchMap(seconds => timer(0, 1000).pipe(map(n => seconds - n)),
    takeWhile(n => n >= 0),
  )
}
```

But this gives me error saying `this: this Argument of type 'Observable<number>' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void | ObservableInput<any>'. Type 'Observable<number>' provides no match for the signature '(): void | ObservableInput<any>'.` at this.duration.

Comment: Please use only tags that are relevant to your question. For instance, AngularJS is a discontinued framework, while Angular is in its 14th version. It is unlikely that one would be using the two in the same project. Likewise, one is unlikely to be using rxjs v5 and rxjs v6 in the same project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a setter to feed `@Input()` changes into a `ReplaySubject`, then define your `timeRemaining$` to start from the subject:

```js
export class CountDownComponent {

  private duration$ = new ReplaySubject<number>(1);

  @Input() set duration(value: number) {
    this.duration$.next(value);
  }

  timeRemaining$ = this.duration$.pipe(
    switchMap(duration => timer(0, 1000).pipe(
      map(n => (duration - n) * 1000),
      takeWhile(n => n >= 0),
    ))
  );

}
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-angular-countdown-jvfyay?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcount-down%2Fcount-down.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demo.

Comment: This works, but I need to use defer here and also need a change handler.
https://netbasal.com/getting-to-know-the-defer-observable-in-rxjs-a16f092d8c09

Comment: why do you need to use defer? what do you mean "change handler"?

Comment: given input can change after the component is created , so I think a change handler is required. I am not sure though.

Comment: with the above code, when a new duration value is received, the timer will be reset to begin with the new duration.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing timers like this:

```
const duration = 60;

timer$
  .range(0, duration + 1)
  .map(i => duration - i)
  .subscribe(i => console.log(i));
```

Then use seconds to minutes function